# How to achieve password error like this in TextInputLayout Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

[image: password error]

This is what I want to achieve. And please help me with the regex for the third error.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `isErrorEnabled` and `error` atributes of your TextInputLayout instance.

```
const val PASSWORD_PATTERN = ...// your regex

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.checkPasswordButton.setOnClickListener {
            val password = binding.passwordEditText.text.toString()
            val isPasswordValid = 
                Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN).matcher(password).matches()
            binding.passwordInputLayout.isErrorEnabled = !isPasswordValid
            val passwordError = if (isPasswordValid) "" else 
                                getString(R.string.invalid_password)
            binding.passwordInputLayout.error = passwordError
        }
    }
}
```